# How can I  show an local html content in adobe air application?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I want to show a local html file into my application but I could't find to do that.

I used `<mx:HTML>` component with using its `location` property but it is not working when I try to do it with a local file which is in applicationdirectory.

I am new on adobe air and actionscript.

Hope you can hellp me out to find a solution.

Thanks

**EDIT: Here is my code :**

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[   
        private function init():void {
            mybrowser.location = "http://www.google.com/maps";
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
```

Comment: Don't understand why you need code. But i will edit my code if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTMLLoader object.

Tutorials + sample code:

http://jurnal.tripmedia.ro/adobe-air-html-tutorial/1732.html
http://www.donotyet.com/2009/09/18/how-to-render-pdf-content-in-air-with-source-code/
http://www.badu.ro/?tag=htmlloader

Answer (score 1):

Using htmlText property:

<mx:HTML htmlText="your html content"/>